# Redirect to specific page after WooCommerce User Registration

Tags: php, redirect, woocommerce

Once people register on the WooCommerce Sign Up page, I am trying to redirect them to a specific page (post id 27). I have tried two different codes but without luck.

```
/* Test 1 */

function filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect( $var ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return get_page_link(27); // 3598 id page id.
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 
    'filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect', 10, 1 );

/* Test 2 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_redirection_after_registration', 10, 1 );
function custom_redirection_after_registration( $redirection_url ){
    // Change the redirection Url
    $redirection_url = get_home_url(); // Home page

    return $redirection_url; // Always return something
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Try setting a higher priority, for example: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect', 999, 1 );`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Thanks, that's really strange. It does not work for me. I tried adding the higher priority but still nothing happens.

Comment: Try replacing the `woocommerce_registration_redirect` filter with `registration_redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

    /*
     * woocommerce_login_redirect is filter hook, by woocommerce
     *
     */
    add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect','All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_Register_Login_Redirect', 10, 2 
    );

    /*
     * woocommerce_registration_redirect is filter hook, by woocommerce
     *
     */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect','All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_Register_Redirect', 10, 1);

    /*
     * login_redirect is filter hook, by woocommerce
     *
     */
    add_filter( 'login_redirect','All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_WP_Login_Redirect', 10, 3);
    
    /*
     * wp_logout is filter hook, by woocommerce
     *
     */
    add_action( 'wp_logout','All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_Register_Logout_Redirect');

function All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_Register_Login_Redirect( $redirec_url, $user ) {
    $redirec_url = home_url();
    // $redirec_url = " add your page link here" ;
    return $redirec_url;
}

function All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_Register_Logout_Redirect() {

    $redirec_url = home_url();
    // $redirec_url = " add your page link here" ;

    wp_redirect( $redirec_url);
    exit();
}

function All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_Register_Redirect( $redirec_url) {
    
    $redirec_url = home_url();
    // $redirec_url = " add your page link here" ;
    return $redirec_url;
}

function All_In_One_Redirect_After_Login_WP_Login_Redirect( $redirec_url, $request, $user) {
    
   $redirec_url = home_url();
    // $redirec_url = " add your page link here" ;
    return $redirec_url;
}

this the free plugin [Woocommerce Redirect After Registration – Login – And Logout][1], that have solved your issue.


  [1]: https://worldwincoder.com/product/woocommerce-redirect-after-registration-login-and-logout/
```